# How to get Object from json /

Tags: android, json

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%22+Kozhikode+%22&sensor=true

This is my json data and how to get latitude and longitude from this json data //

Comment: What have you tried? This is just [JSON parsing](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). Show some effort first

Comment: try parsing with the help of pojo class

Comment: i want to store latitude and longtitude to a string which get from json data

Comment: Yes we know what you want, but [what have you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Denny using this lat and long i want to get nearest places of this location when  i put this lat and long into another url

Comment: have you tried searching instead of creating another copy of `how to parse JSON` question?

Comment: this is my code

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObj1 = a.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject jsonObj2 = jsonObj1.getJSONObject("geometry");
                                JSONObject jsonObj3 = jsonObj2.getJSONObject("bounds");
                                JSONObject jsonObj4 = jsonObj3.getJSONObject("northeast");
                                String b=jsonObj4.getString("lat");
                                String c=jsonObj4.getString("lng");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is code for getting lat lng from json

```
  List<Double> lat = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> lng = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        for(int i=0;i< jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            lat.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat"));
            lng.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Its i wanted exactly.Thanks Hitesh Gehlot